# Equivariant Loomis-Sikorski-Stone reprsentation theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, group-actions, equivariant-maps

Let $X$ be a set, $\mathcal{B}$ a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ and $\mu$ a probability measure on $(X,\mathcal{B})$.

Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\sigma$-subalgebra of $\mathcal{B}$. Then, the Loomis-Sikorski representation theorem tells us that $\mathcal{C}$ is actually isomorphic to the quotient of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{N}$ of some measure space $(Y,\mathcal{N},\mu')$ by the $\sigma$-ideal of $\mu'$-negligible sets.

Now suppose some countable group $G$ acts on $X$ in a measure preserving way, that is, for every $g \in G$, the function $X \to X$ given by $x \mapsto gx$ is a Borel isomorphism and $\mu(gA) = \mu(A)$ for every $A \in \mathcal{B}$.

Is there an equivariant version of the Loomis-Sikorski-Stone representation theorem? I'm wondering whether the following statement is true:

> If $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\sigma$-subalgebra of $\mathcal{B}$ closed under the action of $G$, then there exists some measure space $(Y,\mathcal{N},\mu')$ and some measure preserving action of $G$ on $Y$ such that $\mathcal{C}$ is $G$-isomorphic to the quotient of $\mathcal{N}$ by the $\sigma$-ideal of $\mu'$-negligible sets.

A reference, tip or counterexample would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I've just ran through the proof of the Stone representation theorem and everything works if we carry through the action of $G$ to the Stone space $\{0,1\}^{\mathcal{B}}$ associated to $\mathcal{B}$, so there is an equivariant version if we forget $\sigma$-additivity. Now the question is whether it still holds in the Loomis-Sikorski case.

Comment: Also, Loomis' argument seems to hold up as well if we keep track of the action of the group on the Stone space. In particular, it induces an action of $G$ on the Baire $\sigma$-algebra of $\{0,1\}^{\mathcal{B}}$ and the $\sigma$-ideal of meager sets is $G$-equivariant (this is true because the shift action of each element of $G$ on $\{0,1\}^{\mathcal{B}}$ is continuous on the product topology). So I'm fairly convinced the statement is true, but it would still be nice to have a reference.

Comment: If you don't require any sort of finiteness condition on $\mu'$ then this is all trivial since you can just take $Y=X$, $\mathcal{N}=\mathcal{B}$, and $\mu'$ the measure that is infinite on all nonempty sets.

Comment: I'm also not familiar with the version of Loomis-Sikorski you seem to be referencing--the version I know just gives an abstract $\sigma$-algebra as the quotient of a $\sigma$-field of sets by a $\sigma$-ideal, not necessarily the null sets for some measure.

Comment: @EricWofsey thank you for the comment! Indeed, I was missing the point that if one starts with a $\sigma$-subalgebra of a given measure algebra, one does not need to apply Stone representation theorem, we just restrict the given measure to the $\sigma$-subalgebra in question (I guess you meaned $\mathcal{N} = \mathcal{C}$ in your comment and one can even take $\mu' = \mu$). The measured version of Loomis-Sikorski I was mentioning was Exercise 3 in this post: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/12/245b-notes-1-the-stone-and-loomis-sikorski-representation-theorems-optional/